# RegExp only finding first value

Tags: javascript, regex, function

So I'm making a em to px convertor that when you paste css in the "px" textarea, it converts every px value to em.  It works if you put in something like "padding: 10px;" and then convert, but if you put in "padding: 10px 0 40px 0;" it only changes "10px" to "10em".  I want it to convert all of them, not just stop at the first.  Any ideas?

Here's the jsFiddle :: http://jsfiddle.net/CJamj/

```
        function pxToEm(){
        var px = document.getElementById("px"),
            em = document.getElementById("em"),
            parent = document.getElementById("parent-font-size");

        var pxVal = px.value.match(/\d+/g);
        var pxToEm = 1 / parent.value * pxVal;
        var pxToEmFixed = pxToEm.toFixed(3);
        var pxToEmAnswer = px.value.replace(pxVal, pxToEmFixed).replace("px", "em");

        em.value = pxToEmAnswer;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript replace() method searches a first string for a specified value and returns a new string where the specified values are replaced. There is no such method replaceAll() exists in javascript. So to achieve this we have to use the regular expressions for searching within the string.

The easiest way is, use a regular expression with "g" flag to replace all instances:

Try this:

```
px.value.replace(pxVal, pxToEmFixed).replace(/px/g, "em")
```

Converts px to em:

```
function pxToEm(){
    var px = document.getElementById("px"),
    em = document.getElementById("em"),
    parent = document.getElementById("parent-font-size");

    var pxVal = px.value.match(/\d+px/g).toString().split(',');
    var lengthValue = pxVal.length;

    var pxToEmAnswer;
    for(var i = 0; i < lengthValue; i++)
    {
        var valueToBeReplced = pxVal[i].replace(/px/g, "");;
        var valueToBeReplcedExp = new RegExp(valueToBeReplced, "ig");
        pxToEmAnswer = px.value.replace(valueToBeReplcedExp,  (1/parseInt(parent.value) * valueToBeReplced).toFixed(3));
    }
    em.value = pxToEmAnswer.replace(/px/g, "em");
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CJamj/1/)

Comment: Thanks!  That solves the problem with the labels.  Now, I need to figure out how to do the equation for all! ;b

Comment: You might want to add the ignore case flag `i` too, as in `.replace(/px/ig, "em");`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that really didn't solve the problem with it not converting the digit value though :(

Comment: Actually, yes.  Adding "i" does make a difference.  It converts the first value, but not any other ones.

Comment: Add "ig" to both "/\d+/g" and "/px/g" ?  I know if I do that all "px" changes to "em".  But I want to calculate the "px" values to "em" as well.